# Rationalize $\frac{1}{t^\frac12+t^\frac32}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Rationalize $$\dfrac{1}{t^\frac12+t^\frac32}$$ My try $$\dfrac{1}{t^\frac12+t^\frac32}\cdot\dfrac{t^\frac12-t^\frac32}{t^\frac12-t^\frac32}=\dfrac{t^\frac12-t^\frac32}{t-t^3}$$ How to continue?

Comment: Since you'll never get rid of $\sqrt{t}$ I have no idea what "rationalize" means here.

Comment: Are you posting entire assignment sheet, one problem at a time?

Comment: @MyMolecules, I am posting the problems that I can't solve by myself while preparing for an exam this week. I don't see what's wrong with that as I have clearly shown my effort on all of the problems.

Comment: @mat1 The problems are very similar. Are you not learning anything from previously solved problems? The site is not for homework assisting in this manner.

Comment: @MyMolecules, if you show me one thing (idea etc) I can use from the previous questions here in this problem, I will say I'm wrong. Bye till then. You look at the problems too superficially.

Comment: @ancientmathematician, well we are supposed to get rid of all of the roots in the denominator, yes.

Comment: Then I suggest you find a better set of exercises to do. This is trivially $\frac{\sqrt{t}}{t(1+t)}$

Comment: In some contexts, "rationalize" means "get rid of the radicals/surds in the denominator". Thus, strictly speaking, you've (sort of) done it, but the solution is not the simplest possible. Maybe it will help to write $t^{1/2}$ as $\sqrt{t}$ and $t^{3/2}$ as $t\sqrt{t}$ - this will help you see exactly where those radicals are!

Comment: @StinkingBishop, yep, that helped me a lot. $$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{t}+\sqrt{t^3}}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{t}+t\sqrt{t}}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{t}(1+t)}=\dfrac{\sqrt{t}}{t(t+1)}$$

Comment: @StinkingBishop Is it always easier to do it this way instead of using exponents?

Comment: If we were all computers, it should not matter - those are equivalent ways of writing the same thing. Being human, we all have our preferences. Maybe there are some people who can see it better the other way. I don't know. Happens to be easier this way for me, and seemingly for you. That is all that matters!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continue:
$$\dfrac{t^\frac12-t^\frac32}{t-t^3} = \dfrac{t^\frac 12(1-t)} {t(1-t^2)}=\dfrac{t^\frac 12(1-t)} {t(1+t)(1-t)} =  \dfrac{\sqrt t} {t(1+t)} $$